# How do I set the Windows network timeout for physically disconnected mapped drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

When a network drive ([`net use`](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html)) is physically disconnected, Windows Explorer (and other programs) keeps trying to enumerate and/or use it for maybe 60 seconds.

Is there some way to reduce this timeout to maybe 5 seconds?

Just to clarify, I'm not asking about network drives that are automatically disconnected by Windows after a certain period of time, or about automatic reconnections during login.

The question is about this:

Connect a network drive to another computer. Then turn that other computer off. Then try to reconnect the network drive, e.g. by double-clicking in Windows Explorer → very long timeout. How do I reduce this timeout?

Comment: You might be looking for this: http://superuser.com/a/332754/124651

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for the bounty. But I think people still misunderstand. I tried to rephrase the question again to make it clearer.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg No problem, if you've got time to test some of the new answers, that'd be handy. :)

Comment: None of the registry changes suggested in the answers seem to help. I suspect that the timeout we would like to reduce is actually not a SMB timeout, but a more generic TCP/IP timeout (or a combination of several of them).

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 7 and Vista mapped network drives will disconnect themselves after a time and show a red cross on the drive icon. You will still be able to click on the drive and see/use the contents but applications that require a network drive will see them as disconnected and will not see files. If you try to disconnect the drive, it will still sit there saying 'Disconnected Network Drive' - the only solution is to reboot.
This is because there is a default disconnect time for inactive network connections. To correct this and turn the autodisconnect off do the following:

1. Open the command prompt as Administrator. To do this, either:

   - go to Start → All Programs → Accessories, right-click "Command Prompt" and select "Start as Administrator", or
   - type **cmd** into the search box and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. In the command prompty, type the following:

   ```
   net config server /autodisconnect:-1
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Reboot computer

Your mapped network drives should now stay connected - this is a permanent fix.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs actual question, original request was  misunderstood, see OP's edit.

Comment: I know it is unrelated to OP, but this is exactly what I am looking for, but get access denied. I'm an Admin on my PC.

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://web.archive.org/web/20140916223632/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2013/03/27/smb-2-x-and-smb-3-0-timeouts-in-windows.aspx, it looks like the Windows share timeout is controlled by the "Request Expiration Timer" registry entry.

```
\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\
Value type: Dword  
Value name: SessTimeout
Default:    60 seconds (Windows Vista)
```

It also mentions that this value was reduced to 20s in Windows 8 for quick failover with SMB 3.0.

Comment: Unfortunately, my testing shows that this setting has no effect on the timeout involved in waiting for unavailable network drives. I set it to 5 seconds and I'm still waiting the same ~30 seconds (Windows 7) I was before I set it (and rebooted).

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, but initially it was only around 30 seconds. But when it jumped to around 2 minutes (for some unknown reason), it got so annoying, I had to find a way to solve it.

I have created batch script which tests the network by seeing if it can ping the target machine, if it can, it maps the drives (if unmapped), otherwise, it deletes the mapping.

```
@echo off

set ipaddr=192.168.5.3

set current=neither

:begin

    set state=down

    for /f %%i in ('ping -n 1 %ipaddr% -w 1000 ^| findstr /C:"Received = 1"') do (
        set state=up
    )

    if not %state% == %current% (
        set current=%state%
        if %state% == up (
            net use R: \\%ipaddr%\archive$
        )
        if %state% == down (
            net use R: /delete /y
        )
    )

    sleep 5

goto begin
```

That script is then called by a scheduled task, which runs the script every 10 minutes, with a maximum task time of 10 minutes. Although the console window then remains open during this time, I am currently investigating the `Network Conditions` for this in the scheduler settings, which could be set to create the shares when connected to the network I know the share is on (which would set a flag), and a second script, which would run once ever 5 minutes or so, which if the flag was older than at least however long, it would delete the shares, minimizing console window time.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this kind of solution is about as good as we can expect (still, as of 2014), as least when it comes to logins/Explorer start-up delays caused by the network drives.  Have my bounty.  Perhaps we can revisit it again in a couple more years. :)

Comment: `sleep` in your script is not a native command. Better use a vbscript in this case.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Did you ever find a real solution to this problem? I have a network drive which is often physically powered off, and trying to access it from a client machine results in a frustrating delay.

Answer (score 3):

This worked to me on Windows 7 as expected. Also it solves a long wait after login. Pasted here as a .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider]
"RestoreConnection"=dword:00000000
"RestoreTimeout"=dword:00000004
"DeferConnection"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters]
"SessTimeout"=dword:0000000a
"ExtendedSessTimeout"=dword:00000000
"ReconnectTimeout"=dword:00000004
```

Comment: This doesn't work on 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is below;

Kill the long "restoring network connections" at logon (defer=ghosted connections)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider]

"RestoreConnection"=dword:00000001 ;(0=no attempt, you must click it)

"RestoreTimeout"=dword:00000005
```

Ghost the connection if not responding within `RestoreTimeout`

```
"DeferConnection"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Any source for where you got this information from, or one that hints at why it might help?

Comment: Unfortunately, my testing shows that this setting has no effect on the timeout involved in waiting for unavailable network drives. I created the above keys and set their values, but I'm still waiting the same ~30 seconds (Windows 7) I was before I set it (and rebooted).

Comment: There is also:[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters]
"ReconnectTimeout"=dword:00000005    found here: http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/274680-timeout-mapping-network-drives-windows-login.html      Setting this entry plus the ones above all to 1 seems to make a huge difference (after reboot). Now everything is fast as expected again.

Comment: Searching microsoft.com, I was not able to find any information on `DeferConnection`. I was able to find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/overriding-the-default-mpr-time-out-interval which reveals that the RestoreTimeout value is measured in milliseconds, and that the default would have been 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post on [Windows7Hacker](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2011/03/how-to-fix-the-red-x-on-the-icon-of-mapped-network-drives-in-windows-7/), fixing this issue on the client side involves a registry edit.

1. Open the Registry with **Regedit.exe**
2. Naviagate to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters`
3. Create a **DWORD** value named `KeepConn` and set it to time in seconds to keep the connection alive

For example, I set it to *86400* (one day).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also, as a general reminder: Try to make your answers longer than a sentence and add some context please. Explain how the link actually answers the question – it might not be that obvious.

Comment: @IvoFlipse: Sure. Thanks for the suggesstion.

Comment: @slhck: Will keep that in mind.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs actual question, original request was  misunderstood, see OP's edit.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

> > waiting for unavailable network drives. I created the above keys and set their values, but I'm still waiting the same ~30 seconds (Windows 7) <<

I have been bashing my head against it in Win10 with the difference that the timeout **has increased from 30 sec to five minutes.

This seems to work

**netsh interface tcp set global initialRto=300**

300 appears to reset it to 30sec ...and that appears to be the minimum setting allowed .

In any case, 30 sec compared to 5 minutes is a huge improvement.

Since it is TCP related, I'm expecting that it may be too short for other internet related timeouts and expect to be fiddling with over time.

Comment: This works via a lot of indirection and has other effects, too. It actually sets the initial TCP retransmission timeout (for *all* TCP connections on the machine) to 300 milliseconds. So, for example, any time you try to establish a TCP connection and you don't get the ACK back in 300 ms, the SYN will be re-transmitted. This is not ideal behaviour. If I find a better solution for this specific problem, I'll let you know.