# How can I cancel opening a folder in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I am forced to use a Windows machine for some parts of my job, but I am not a Windows guy, so there may be some obvious solution to this that I am missing.

Sometimes, when I am browsing files in Explorer, I accidentally click on the wrong folder which happens to lead to a network drive. Explorer dutifully tries to open said folder. Even if I am connected to the Internet this can take a few seconds, and when I'm *not* connected to the Internet (working remotely) it sometimes takes upwards of 30 seconds.

I'd like a way to be able to stop Explorer from opening that folder after I've clicked on it, so I don't have to wait 30 seconds for it to get the contents of the folder just to go back a folder when I *know* I've clicked on the wrong thing. Basically a sort of equivalent for Ctrl-C in a *nix environment during a long-running operation.

My current workaround is to open a new Explorer window when I do this because that tends to be faster. The obvious response is "don't click on the wrong folder," but clearly I am going to make mistakes once in a while, and it's annoying to lose those 30 seconds when I'm trying to get work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - that instance of Explorer is waiting for the network subsystem to respond.

The ~30 seconds is the networking subsystem's time-out that happens so you're not waiting forever when the network location doesn't answer. :)

Starting a new instance of Explorer is probably the fastest/easiest work-around.

Perhaps check out this related SU question about the same problem: [How to set the Windows network timeout for physically disconnected mapped drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/453741/how-to-set-the-windows-7-network-timeout)

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but at least it tells me I haven't been missing something obvious. Thanks.