# Unavailable Network Share causes Explorer (and its dependants) to hang for huge amounts of time

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1

So, I have a laptop, and a desktop, both Windows 8.1. The laptop follows me wherever I go, and the desktop doesn't. The desktop has 5 external drives, and I am using Storage Spaces to pool the drives together. I have shared the resultant drive (REFS format) on my network, and have mapped to a drive letter on my laptop. So far, so good.

However, when I take the laptop off my home network to, say, the office, whenever I try to open a program that enumerates drives, the system hangs while it tries to connect to the drives. When I open Explorer at the office, it shows the network drive as available, but hangs for a long time, then discovers the network drive is not present.

I have confirmed that this hang is being caused by the mapped drive, because after disconnecting it, the hanging stops and everything goes back to normal.

I have experienced the hanging with the following software:

- Explorer
- FileZilla (takes about 2 minutes to open)
- Skype (when saving a file)
- Sublime Text 2 (first time a file dialog box is opened)
- Oxygen XML Editor (any file dialog operation)

Is there anything I can do to either change the timeout when testing a network drives existence, or telling the system to ignore mapped drives unless specifically called?

I have tried working with just shortcuts to the network shares, but with some of the software I use, they don't support explicit network shares (Oxygen XML), and manual intervention would completely undermine the file version history tracker I have set up (would only index bulk commits made during a manual copy, rather than each and every change as I go along).

---

**Additional**

I found this issue originally in FileZilla last year at some point, and after raising a case with FileZilla, they came back saying that the hang was being caused by a lower level system component. The only difference between then and now is, then, I was on Windows 8, and the network drive was a single drive instead of storage spaces drive. Sadly, I can't find the case, but there are many others like it.

At that point, I gave up and resigned myself to slow FileZilla startup times, however, the hanging at that time was around 30 seconds, and now it has jumped to 2 minutes, so I really want this problem solved.

Comment: "network drive was a single drive instead of a single drive" this statement does not make sense in the context of the sentence.

Comment: Disconnect the drive / remove laptop from network / ... / connect laptop to network / connect the drive? You can probably write a couple of batch files to make this easier ... See [NET USE](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) and the `/delete` option.

Comment: @Ramhound apologies, edited

Comment: @DavidPostill let's call that plan b, but I like it. Just have a setup script, a destroy script, and a poller script. When it detects its not there (when not destroyed), run destroy, when it finds it (when not setup), run setup

Comment: Sounds good to me ... :) not sure how you would do the "polling" though ... would that just "hang"? ...

Comment: @DavidPostill well, I wouldn't poll the share as that would cause the same issue, but I could ping the server instead, and then test a file shared from the local disk (just to confirm that I haven't accidentally connected to a network with the same ip address on it)

Comment: That might work ... :)

Comment: @cgoddard Regardless of age it's still the same question (IMO anyway).  If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question please [place a bounty on it](http://superuser.com/help/bounty).

Comment: @cgoddard The answers on that dupe DO stink, they're not really answering the question, so I stuck a 100pt bounty on it myself. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 would love to, but the bounty system hasn't ever served well, especially when the question is esoteric in nature. all that happens is reputation points are lost (after only 1 week!!!). I agree with your opinion though, but I disagree that bounties are the way to do that. Although bumping has now been relegated to the Microsoft Q&A sites, it has been far more effective in reviving a stale question. Only thing is, you have to sift through page after page of "me too", but better that than risk loosing hard earned reputation for a question that only a handful of people care about

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 QUICK!!! POST YOUR ANSWER FROM http://superuser.com/questions/332582/!!! It works nicely!

Comment: What else were you planning on using the Rep for, retirement? :)

Comment: I considered that, but my answer from the other doesn't directly answer it (to me anyway). ;) I've got 100rep to burn, so we'll see what comes up.  If someone wants to copy my answer and make it fit/answer the other question, I'll give them the points. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have been suckered into gamification, sue me! But in that case, I will post my modified solution there

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 there we go, took a while (got distracted), but hopefully, that should have that question with a working solution, well, until windows or something changes and the problem goes away