# Endless load in Explorer while disconnected from corporate network

Tags: windows-10, dns, windows-explorer, mapped-drive

I've got the problem that Explorer is showing the green loading bar (Green Bar of Death) while disconnected from corporate network. It doesn't matter if connected with DHCP and internet access or just a pure network connection without other clients (APIPA) or even with disconnected NIC.

I tracked it down to the name resolution with disconnected network shares/mapped drives (from GPO). I barely can access files on local physical drives. I can't even open notepad and use the "open file" dialog since it also shows mapped drives.

In Wireshark I can see that Windows tries to reach for the file server.

- LLMNR (multicast DNS)
- NBNS (NetBIOS)
- DNS

As soon as I add the file server with `127.0.0.1` in the `hosts` file, the green loading bar vanishes and I am able to access local drives again.

I also already tried to adjust timeout settings from these posts without success:

- [How do I set the Windows network timeout for physically disconnected mapped drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/453741/how-do-i-set-the-windows-network-timeout-for-physically-disconnected-mapped-driv)
- [How do I stop mapped network drives which aren't available preventing Windows 7 64-bit booting past KSOD?](https://superuser.com/questions/332582/how-do-i-stop-mapped-network-drives-which-arent-available-preventing-windows-7/332754#332754)

Question:
What can I do to prevent this **long** loading/availability check for mapped drives?

Comment: any mapped network drives/folders from the FS?

Comment: @Zina Sorry I dont't understand the question... I'm in the "My Computer" drives overview while this happens. Accessing drives logically should only work for local drives since the file server is unavailable which hosts all mapped drives.

Comment: just sharing my experience, I had a shared drive on my remote PC and when it was not available on the network I also have seen long times of loading when unavailable. in my case it was my Z: drive mapped to a shared folder. the fix was to unmap or hhave the server available.

Comment: Anything that avoids the scenario is no fix in my eyes.

Comment: well, in my case the fix was fixing the remote server - as it was unavailable on the network, and there is nothing else I could do as Windows Explorer was trying to reach the location until the time-out was reached.

Comment: In my case it's because of technicians who are out of house and unable to establish a vpn connection because of limited resources in the location they're working at (at customer's basement for example).

Comment: I believe we have the same issue. My NAS changed IP address and now every application I open that has a "Recent Files" list hangs for a few minutes if I accidentally mouse over it, just because I had opened files from the NAS on the old IP in the past.

Comment: You can clear the "Recent Files" list via folder options. I think it's a different problem with network shares connected with drive letters.