# Windows 7 starts to an empty black screen

Tags: windows-7, black-screen-of-death

So everything was working fine, and then last night I dont know if related to the time change, the computer froze. It was late so I switched it off and thought about dealing with it this morning, now when I try to access it after logon screen, I just have a black screen with the mouse, which I can move, but right click wont show up any context menu, and windows key or ctrl+alt+del won't make anything happen either.

I've tried safe mode and  restoring the system, but both leads me to the same empty screen.

Any suggestion is really appreciated, 
thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Windows 7 Black screen of death](http://superuser.com/q/79421), [Windows 7 hangs on black screen for a while after log in](http://superuser.com/q/260050)

Comment: @DavidPostill Before posting a question I always look for the answer in related questions, but thank you

Comment: Next time please let us know in your question that you have looked. It saves us looking on your behalf :/

Comment: I wouldnt say you looked so much, you referred me to 2 unsolved questions. But thank you anyway

Comment: Just because there are no accepted answers doesn't mean that some of the answers are not applicable to your situation. Have you looked at all of the answers in the two links to see if they apply to your case?